# detect empty field - problem

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying detect in ajax what is the field that is empty. (`echo $field;`  >>> output is radios)

This  `if (!data.livre && data.livre == "radios") {` checks if `data.livre` is not true (that is working) and now i want to check if the echo is radios or not. If is radios i showed to the user: empty radios

```
function check($form) {
            $fields = array("radios", "age");
            foreach($fields as $field) {
                if(empty($form[$field])) {
                    echo $field;
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
    }

    $data = array();
    $data['livre'] = $val-> check($form);
    echo json_encode($data);
```

**JSON output:**

```
radios{"livre":false}
```

**js**

```
        success: function(data) {
             if (!data.livre && data.livre == "radios") { //problem here
                $("#msgbox1").fadeTo(200, 0.1, function() {
                 $(this).html('empty radios').addClass('messageboxerror1').fadeTo(900, 1);      
                });
            }
        }
```

**EDIT: What is the best way to identify if the field that is empty is radios or age ?**

thanks

Comment: What is the problem?  It is hard to understand this question.

Comment: i need to check if the json is: radios{"livre":false}
 or age{"livre":false} basically

Comment: `!data.livre && data.livre == "radios"` is essentially saying "if livre isn't set and equals 'radios'..." Did you want to use || instead?

Comment: It doesn't make sense either way. The json output you are generating is not valid. If you want to check it using data.livre you would have to write it like `{"livre": "radios"}`.

Comment: ok, and to check this {"livre":"radios"} --->  data.livre == "radios" didn't work

Comment: Obviously because you're checking if it is not set AND if it is "radios". That can never be true... Remove the !data.livre

Comment: man, i am totally confused. I think the problem is clear now. What is the best way to identify if the field that is empty is radios or age ?

Comment: Your PHP is wrong. You have `echo` in your `function check()`. That's wrong. That echoes "radio" at some point. That breaks your javascript because you output something JS parser can't understand. Basically, remove that echo. After you receive valid JSON back, then we can move forward with debugging.

Comment: @Michael J.V anyway this not solve the issue. {"livre":"false"} can be radios or age.

Comment: That's why I said that after you fix your PHP, we can move on to debugging the rest. What's wrong is that you don't really understand what you did there with PHP. `true` or `false` is stored in your data.livre, that's it. You can't check if your `data.livre` is true OR false and then if it has a third value.

Comment: i think the best option is just echo ($field) and with  dataType: "text", check if the text is radios or age.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the result can be that only radios or age or none of both can be empty then you have to edit your check to `!data.livres || data.livres == "radios" || data.livres == "age"`. It will then print the message if your json output is the following:

```
{livres: false}
```

or

```
{livres: "radios"}
```

or

```
{livres: "age"}
```

Edit: Changes according to your comment

```
if (!data.livre) { //problem here
  // Do whatever you want to do when livres is false
} else if (data.livre == "radios") {
  // Do whatever you want to do when livres is "radios"
} else if (data.livre == "age") {
  // Do whatever you want to do when livres is "age"
}
```

Comment: I must have a switch to check if is the radios >> show a message "empty radios" or if is the age >> show a message "empty age". what you suggest always will show the same message.